# Strange `clear: both;` bug using WebKit

Tags: css, webkit

I am developing a website for a Curling Club in France.
When you open the website http://www.bcc.ionyse.com/ with Firefox you don't have any problem.
But if you try using webkit, the right column disappear.

Do you know what's wrong ? I am guessing some `clear` or `overflow` CSS properties are missing but I cannot figure out how.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks you have assigned excessive width to the sidebar.

Comment: What do you mean by sidebar ? Should I set the width of .left-column and .right-column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I inspected it in [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com) and Chrome's Developer tools, it appears that when I turned off the `overflow: auto;` in Chrome, it put it back in the right place, but the content is below the content in the left column.

I'd suggest re-writing the HTML to keep the columns more separate.